# Pass setState to axios inside handler function (React)

Tags: reactjs

This is my component, stripped down of all the nice stuff:

```js
const MyOtherComp = ({message}) => {
    return (
      <div className="message">{message}</button>
    )
}

class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  state = {
    fileUploadMessage: "",
  }

  handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('post-url',
      formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(this)
        this.setState({fileUploadMessage: response})
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response)
      })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                      <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                      <MyOtherComp message={this.state.fileUploadMessage} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComp
```

As you can see, I've bounded the `this` object of the upper component - `MyComp` - to the `this` object of the `handleSubmit` handler.

What I expect: Upon `axios`'s return, the `this` object of `handleSubmit` should contain a method called `setState`, since the `MyComp` component has it (as all React class component do). So - `this` in the scope of `axios` should be the same as the scope of `handleSubmit`.
What actually happens: When I check the `this` object (see the `console.log` inside the `then` clause) it is `undefined`.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new function inside `.then` which creates new scope of `this`. Change it to an arrow function and it should work -

```
.then((response) => {
    console.log(this)
    this.setState({fileUploadMessage: response})
 })
```

If you don't want to use an arrow function then

```
.then(function (response) {
   console.log(this)
   this.setState({fileUploadMessage: response})
}.bind(this))
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct, this works now! Let's say I wanted to keep my original, non-arrow function. Why wouldn't another bind suffice? I tried and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @t0mgs If you don't want to use an arrow function then you have to use a named function and bind it's value of `this`.. EDIT: I just updated my answer. try and see if it works?